# Bootstrap date selector; enable month selection ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I've been trying to get bootstrap text box for selecting a month; which is identified by using `type="month"`. Same can be applied to select a week; `type="week"`, with c# data annotations.
But, no luck. 
I'm able to create a bootstrap date selector by using following data annotations;

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public virtual DateTime Month { get; set; }
```

But, unable to create a field to select month. I tried using `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM}")]` 
and following;
`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Month, new { @Value = Model.Month.ToString("d") })` as given in 
http://geekswithblogs.net/80n/archive/2012/04/27/apply-a-datetime-format-in-an-asp.net-mvc-textboxfor.aspx
which gave me a different error.

Please see the attach image ; bootstrap month selector.
[image]

Note; I'm using razor for the view.

Help much appreciated.